# Шаблон номера для нумерованного списка

Tags: html, css

Нужен нумерованный список следующего вида:

R001. текст
R002. текст
..
R123. текст

Требования такие:

1. Маркер элемента списка состоит из строки и порядкового номера.
2. Строка не меняется, но её нужно задать явно.
3. Порядковый номер дополнен нулями до нужной разрядности, её тоже нужно задать явно.

Как реализовать это на CSS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вариант с нулями

```css
ol.requirement{
  padding-left: 0;
}
ol.requirement li {
  counter-increment: req;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol.requirement li:before {
  content: "R0" counter(req, decimal-leading-zero) ". ";
}

ol.requirement li:nth-child(n+100):before {
  content: "R" counter(req, decimal-leading-zero) ". ";
}
```

```html
<ol class="requirement">
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
 <li>text</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Какой хитрый трюк.

Comment: А что можно сделать с отступом?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin какой отступ необходимо убрать?

Answer (score 4):

Не смог только настроить количество нулей и в новом списке слишком большой отступ.

```css
ol.requirement li {
  counter-increment: req;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol.requirement li:before {
  content: "R" counter(req, decimal-leading-zero) ". ";
}
```

```html
Специальный список:

<ol class="requirement">
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
</ol>

Для сравнения, обычный список:

<ol>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Отступы у них одинаковые, просто списки свои псевдообозначения (числа, буллеты) располагают слева, игнорируя левый паддинг. В общем, поменяйте `padding-left` у нужного вам списка.

Comment: @DaemonHK я почти впервые что-то делаю с css, не понимаю как устроены расстояния. Наверное, задам новый вопрос про это.

Comment: У списков по умолчанию есть внешние отступы (`margin`) сверху и снизу и внутренний (`padding`) слева, который и нужно уменьшить для `.requirement`